# How to copy and paste more than 1000 rows from data.tree/console in R studio

Tags: r, excel

I have a data.tree environment object which I want to move to excel. Currently, the object has well over 1000 rows thus when printing in Rstudio, I cannot copy and paste all of it back to excel. writing the environment to another file has also failed. I have further tried to increase the rows over 1000 with the option in global options under code and display, which did not increase the total row count. Anyone have any ideas?

```
library(readr)
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
library(data.tree)

categories <- read_csv("W:/categories.csv")
df <- categories
df <- df[-c(1)]

options(max.print=9000)

str_replace_all(df, "[^[:alnum:]]", "")

df$pathString <- paste(df$Top, df$Manager, df$Employee, df$`sub-employee`, sep="/")
tree <- as.Node(df[,])
print(tree, limit=6000)
```

Comment: This might help you: https://www.johndcook.com/blog/r_excel_clipboard/

Comment: What did you try when writing to a file? That would be a better approach than copy/paste.

Comment: There are heaps of ways of exporting dataframes to csv or Excel files.  What have you tried?

Comment: `readr::write_csv`?

Comment: If you look at what i wrote, its an environmental print output we are attempting to save, not the dataframe. Further, I have tried multiple methods to save the entity, it requires the print command explicitly to provide the desired output. Hence the question....